# Mystery text being entered into my computer

Tags: keylogger

I started having an issue last week with text being entered automatically into my computer. I first noticed it when playing games, where action would occur without my having done a keypress. The next day I opened Discord, and found that ~10 lines of text had been entered into a channel overnight while I was asleep. All of this text was comprised of things I had typed previously into my computer, over the last 6 months at least, maybe more. Not all of it was from one source - some was from emails, some from discord, some from search fields on websites.
To test it out, I left a blank draft email open last night, with the cursor active in the body field. Sure enough this morning it was filled with the same, lines of text followed by a newline, all of which was pulled from something I had typed into the computer previously.

Clearly this is a real issue and likely some sort of infestation, but while I wipe everything and reinstall, I wanted to get an opinion of WHAT was happening. A keylogger could well have been installed at some point, but when why is it re-entering text at random into my computer now? Stealing keypress data seems meaningless if the program is going to show its hand by spamming the logged text back into my computer.

I am working on a desktop PC I have had for about a year and a half, running the newest windows. I am generally good about limiting access to anything sketchy - no torrent files or clicking on links in emails I don't know are authentic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Before wiping everything, you should try to figure out whether you can get information on the program responsible for recording your keystrokes in the first place. If on windows, maybe run Malwarebytes or something similar. Otherwise, you will not get to the bottom of this ;-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SuperUser is a Q and A style website. Questions need a factual answer that can be tested and validated. In this case, the problem no longer exists, thus this can never be fully answered. That turns this into an opinion based question which is considered off-topic as well.

Comment: @LPChip this response feels pedantic. I am asking a Q looking for and A from anyone who may have encountered a similar situation, or had advice on how to identify what is happening. In the meantime I did run Malwarebytes on the machine, which identified 0 threats present.

Comment: You may like it or not, but its stated in the Help Center of SuperUser on what kind of questions you should avoid asking. Asking a question that is only opinion based is not allowed. Given that you stated that you are already in the process of reinstalling and you wanted an opinion, this is clearly against the rules. We're not a forum.